# How to create geometries with multiple outer polygons in mosaic

Tags: geometry, databricks, openstreetmap, spatial, mosaic

I am using Databricks Mosaic, where I am parsing an OSM `PBF` file and trying to convert it into spatial geom types [`line, point, polygon`, etc.].
I am able to process the relation having one `outer` polygon with `st_makepolygon(outer,inner[])` function. However, I am unable to create a spatial geom with multiple `outer` polygons.

Tried using `st_union` on the geom array, but that doesn't work!

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cPsk.png)